# How to add space between words of paragraph to remove space from end in Textview(i.e. Justify Text) in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, text-formatting, justify

I am creating a UI for my application, where I need to show paragraph like this

[image]

And for doing this I have used `Textview` like this

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/dp24"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-thin"
    android:text="@string/sample_description"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:lineSpacingExtra="@dimen/dp4"
    />
```

But my output is like this

[image]

If you notice in my output at the end of some lines there is some space left. And I don't want it.

And if you saw in the 1st image there is no space left at the end. They added space between words to remove space from the end.

So, My question is how to achieve the 1st image output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use Android 8+ you can obtain the justification using

```
android:justificationMode="inter_word".
```

As alternative you can use a `WebView` to place your text into in HTML format:

```
<string name="sporttext">
<![CDATA[
<html>
 <head></head>
 <body style="text-align:justify;color:gray;background-color:white;">
  This sport shirt is crafted from scratch ...
 </body>
</html>
]]>
</string>
```

Comment: Yes, I saw 1st solution only supports Android 8+. And in the 2nd solution, we can use `WebView` but for that, we need HTML content. And I will get this data from Rest API So then I have to do changes in API also right?

Comment: You can use the `WebView` to show the string defined in `strings.xml` by using `webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, getString(R.string.sporttext), "text/html", "utf-8", null);`

Answer (score 3):

The thing you need is called justified content. You can achieve this using

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:justificationMode="inter_word" />
```